# Merge lists of tuples based on its values

Tags: python, list, merge, tuples, key-value

I'm trying to figure out a method to merge two lists in python in order to accomplish something like this:

```
list_a = [(item_1, attribute_x), (item_2, attribute_y), (item_3, attribute_z)]
list_b = [(item_1, attribute_n), (item_3, attribute_p) ]
```

As result:

```
list_result = [(item_1, attribute_x, attribute_n), (item_2, attribute_y, False), (item_3, attribute_z, attribute_p)]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Post some real data. `item_1` is hashable?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting way to solve your problem, this is a robust function that returns a generator:

```
def combine_item_pairs(l1, l2):
    D = {k:[v, False] for k, v in l1}
    for key, value in l2:
        if key in D:
            D[key][1] = value
        else:
            D[key] = [False, value]
    return (tuple([key]+value) for key, value in D.iteritems())
```

Using it:

```
>>> list(combine_item_pairs(list_a, list_b))
[('item_2', 'attribute_y', False), ('item_3', 'attribute_z', 'attribute_p'), ('item_1', 'attribute_x', 'attribute_n')]
```

---

Here is an extra bonus solution (same interface, but more efficient solution:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter as I

def combine_item_pairs(l1, l2):
    return (tuple(list([k]+[I(1)(i) for i in g]+[False])[:3]) for k, g in groupby(sorted(l1+l2), key=I(0)))
```

Results:

```
>>> list(combine_item_pairs(list_a, list_b))
[('item_1', 'attribute_n', 'attribute_x'), ('item_2', 'attribute_y', False), ('item_3', 'attribute_p', 'attribute_z')]
```

**note:** efficiency of this solution is diminished if the lists require much sorting, or if a lot of values are absent. (Also, currently all absences will be reflected by a `False` value only in the last item of the tuple, with no way of knowing which list is missing an item (that's the price of efficiency) this should be used with large data when it is less important to know which list is missing an item)

---

**edit:** Timers:

```
a = [('item_1', 'attribute_x'), ('item_2', 'attribute_y'), ('item_3', 'attribute_z')]
b = [('item_1', 'attribute_n'), ('item_3', 'attribute_p')]

def inbar(l1, l2):
    D = {k:[v, False] for k, v in l1}
    for key, value in l2:
        if key in D:
            D[key][1] = value
        else:
            D[key] = [False, value]
    return (tuple([key]+value) for key, value in D.iteritems())

def solus(l1, l2):
    dict_a,dict_b = dict(l1), dict(l2)
    items = sorted({i for i,_ in l1+l2})
    return [(i, dict_a.get(i,False), dict_b.get(i,False)) for i in items]

import timeit # running each timer 3 times just to be sure.
print timeit.Timer('inbar(a, b)', 'from __main__ import a, b, inbar').repeat()
# [2.2363221572247483, 2.1427426716407836, 2.1545361420851963]
# [2.2058199808040575, 2.137495707329387, 2.178640404817184]
# [2.4588094406466743, 2.4221991975274215, 2.3586636366037856]
print timeit.Timer('solus(a, b)', 'from __main__ import a, b, solus').repeat()
# [5.841498824468664, 5.951693880486182, 5.866254325691159]
# [5.843569212526087, 5.919173415087307, 6.027018876010061]
# [6.41402184345621, 6.229860036924308, 6.562849100520403]
```

Comment: It is a clever solution. However, a simpler method - directly converting the lists to dictionaries and iterating over the unique keys/items - is more efficient, both in memory and CPU usage:
`[(i, a.get(i,False), b.get(i,False)) for i in {item for item,_ in list_a+list_b}]`
I could post the profiling code I used, but it is easy enough to verify.
(Note: Your second more "efficient" solution is actually less efficient and mixes up the order of attributes.)

Comment: Please take a look at the timers. As you can see, you are wrong.

Comment: I had in mind bigger inputs. If instead of merging lists with 3 items a million times, you merge lists with a million items once, the results are reversed. I tested on lists from 100 to 10m items. It is not too much slower on small, non-trivial list sizes, but scales poorly.

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionaries, they are a very flexible and ductile data structure:

```
dic_a = {}
dic_a['item_1'] = []
dic_a['item_1'].append(attribute_x)
```

for each element you can a list of values and then simply append a new value if the key that you want to insert is already existing:

```
if 'item_1' in dic_result:
    dic_result['item_1'].append(attribute_n)
```

Comment: While what you are saying is true - it is not really an attempt to answer the question. Your answer is just an explanation of how a dictionary works. And while a dictionary might be a great solution to this question, you will need to actually provide an answer that is not simply using the information from the question to create a dictionary. (Though I do appreciate your merit, please try a little harder)

Answer (score -1):

Converting to dictionaries and using a list of the unique items:

```
a,b = dict(list_a), dict(list_b)
items = sorted({i for i,_ in list_a+list_b})
```

You can build the tuples as follows:

```
[(i, a.get(i,False), b.get(i,False)) for i in items]
```

Using your example:

```
item_1,item_2,item_3,item_4 = 1,2,3,4
attribute_x,attribute_y,attribute_z,attribute_n,attribute_p = 'x','y','z','n','p'

list_a = [(item_1, attribute_x), (item_2, attribute_y), (item_3, attribute_z)]
list_b = [(item_1, attribute_n), (item_3, attribute_p), (item_4, attribute_n)]

dict_a,dict_b = dict(list_a), dict(list_b)
items = sorted({i for i,_ in list_a+list_b})
list_result = [(i, dict_a.get(i,False), dict_b.get(i,False)) for i in items]

print(list_result)
```

Result:

```
[(1, 'x', 'n'), (2, 'y', False), (3, 'z', 'p'), (4, False, 'n')]
```

Comment: This solution is very wasteful on the memory of the computer, and very inefficient. Also - it will not scale at all, and is not robust. I am sure you can figure out how to fix all those problems, and you should if you want your answer to be comprehensive. At the moment, it is almost akin to a brute force solution.

Comment: @inbar-rose Even with the list concatenation (`itertools.chain` could be more memory efficient) and unnecessary sort, it is surprisingly efficient and scales well. Provided the items are hashable, it is robust, and trivial to extend it to multiple lists of items.
Maybe there is a much more efficient and pythonic solution, but it performs not nearly as badly as you assumed.
In fact, did I mention that it significantly outperforms your "efficient" solutions both in CPU usage and memory, and scales better with both?
(How about that upvote? ;)

Comment: Please take a look at the timers in my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18447026/1561176 as you can see, you are wrong.

Comment: Try timing on input lists with more than 3 elements.